# pipe and log STDOUT at the same time

Tags: io-redirection, pipe

Some programs output very detailed data, for readability I use `awk` to filter them.

```
./output_many_things | awk '{print $1 "\t" $2}'
```

But I don't want to miss anything. Could I redirect the complete output to a log file, but output the `awk`ed data to screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely. Stick [`tee`](http://fclose.com/p/linux/man/1p-tee/) in the pipeline.