# Output to stdout and at the same time grep into a file

Tags: grep, pipe, stdout, tee

I have a script that outputs text to `stdout`. I want to see all this output in my terminal, and at the same time I want to filter some lines and save them in a file. Example:

```
$ myscript
Line A
Line B
Line C

$ myscript | grep -P 'A|C' > out.file

$ cat out.file
Line A
Line C
```

I want to see output of first command in terminal, and save the output of the second command in a file. At the same time. I tried using `tee`, but with no result, or better, with **[reversed result](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36372/pipe-and-log-stdout-at-the-same-time).**

Answer (score 50, accepted):

> I want to see output of first command in terminal, and save the output of the second command in a file.

As long as you don't care whether what you are looking at is from **stdout** or **stderr**, you can still use `tee`:

```
myscript | tee /dev/stderr | grep -P 'A|C' > out.file
```

Will work on linux; I don't know if "/dev/stderr" is equally applicable on other *nixes.

Comment: `/dev/stderr` is common. `/dev/tty` (meaning the current terminal) would also work here, and it's [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap10.html).

Comment: @Gilles: Wonderful. `tee /dev/tty` served wonderfully for my requirement of having to print the `stdout` of a script to terminal and to pipe it to the `stdin` of another command as well! Thankees! :-)

Comment: `/dev/tty` doesn't work on non-interactive terminals it appears. I got `tee: /dev/tty: No such device or address` when automating this on a server, but worked fine locally.

Comment: What's a "non-interactive terminal"?  I think what that usually refers to is a non-interactive *shell* (ie., it's a misnomer). If what you really mean is `myscript` is running *in the background* (as it presumably would be on a server), then the process doesn't have a terminal to output to unless you provide one -- which if `/dev/tty` is "the current terminal" and there isn't one, of course it doesn't work.  -> [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/66378/212479)

Answer (score 10):

```
{ ... | tee /dev/fd/3 | grep -e A -e C > out.file; } 3>&1
```

Or with process substitution (ksh93, zsh or bash):

```
... | tee >(grep -e A -e C > out.file)
```

With zsh:

```
... >&1 > >(grep -e A -e C > out.file)
```

Comment: I found I had to use the first one because it preserves the exit code of grep. Also, if for some reason you cannot access the /dev filesystem, the `/dev/fd/3` can be replaced with `>(cat 1>&3)`

Answer (score 7):

Here's another way with `sed`:

```
myscript | sed '/PATTERN/w out.file'
```

By default, `sed` prints every line it receives from *stdin* (which is `myscript`'s *stdout* in this case) in other words you'll see the entire output of `myscript` on screen.
In addition, all lines matching `PATTERN` will be `w`ritten to a file named `out.file`

Answer (score -1):

you didn't specify how you used the tee command but this should work:

```
myscript | grep -P 'A|C' | tee out.file
```

at least it worked on my server few minutes ago...

Comment: But, if I'm not wrong, this way you *grep* also what's on screen. I want to see **all** output on screen, and filter only what's going into the file.