# Filter partial output of some script

Tags: bash, grep, tee

I need to analyze the output of some script

So, I know their header and their tail of some part of the output script, but not the content.

I found an approach [1] But I need something like:

```
$ myscript
Line A
Line B
Line C
Line D
Line E
Line F

$ myscript | tee /dev/stderr | <some option from C to E> > out.file

$ cat out.file
Line C
Line D
Line E
```

[1] - [Output to stdout and at the same time grep into a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71492/output-to-stdout-and-at-the-same-time-grep-into-a-file)

Comment: You seem to want to remove the first and line, is that correct?

Comment: It seems that the linked question does what you want.