# Pipe/log mix process

Tags: pipe, logs

I am quite novice with Linux. I have a similar need to this post :
[pipe and log STDOUT at the same time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36372/pipe-and-log-stdout-at-the-same-time), but not sure to understand what to do from what is explained :/

I have a command which computes data for several hours and outputs everything in an external log file (log-01) and any error in a dedicated one (log-error) like so:

```
myCommand > log-01 2>log-error
```

But I would like to also display on my terminal the different sequential steps of this process by picking up - from the stream or from log-01? -some specific key words and display any associated data of my choice (basically some following numbers or whole line, depending on the step to he checked). Basically what I would do with a grep instruction.

When my log-01 records thousands of lines, my terminal only displays the 20 sequential steps or so.

Thanks in advance for your tips!

Answer (score 2):

Use `tee`:

```
myCommand 2>log-error | tee log-01
```

Comment: Hi Jayhendren,

Is tee can allow me to apply some filters of what will be displayed on my terminal (I don't want the whole log, only some key parts of it).

Thanks

Comment: Pipe the output of `tee` through `grep`.